# How can we debug SSH logs apart from the verbose (-vvv) command?

Tags: ssh, putty, openssh, debug, embedded-linux

SSH connection is getting closed by port 6655 when trying to SSH into the board using board's IP address using Putty. How can I debug the SSH logs and the process apart from the verbose command?

Verbose log is given below:

```
  mytsp00382@mytsp00382-OptiPlex-7040:/media/mytsp00382/ROOTFS$     ssh -vvv 192.168.10.102  
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.6, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017  
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config  
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *  
debug2: resolving "192.168.10.102" port 6655  
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0  
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.10.102 [192.168.10.102] port 6655.  
debug1: Connection established.  
debug1: identity file /home/mytsp00382/.ssh/id_rsa type 0  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /home/mytsp00382/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /home/mytsp00382/.ssh/id_dsa type -1  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /home/mytsp00382/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /home/mytsp00382/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /home/mytsp00382/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /home/mytsp00382/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1  
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory  
debug1: identity file /home/mytsp00382/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1  
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.6  
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.1  
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000  
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK  
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.10.102:6655 as 'mytsp00382'  
debug3: put_host_port: [192.168.10.102]:6655  
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/mytsp00382/.ssh/known_hosts"  
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/mytsp00382/.ssh/known_hosts:3  
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [192.168.10.102]:6655  
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa  
debug3: send packet: type 20  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent  
debug3: receive packet: type 20  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received  
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal  
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c  
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com  
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com  
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1  
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1  
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib  
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib  
debug2: languages ctos:   
debug2: languages stoc:   
debug2: first_kex_follows 0   
debug2: reserved 0   
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal  
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1  
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa  
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com  
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com  
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1  
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1  
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com  
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com  
debug2: languages ctos:   
debug2: languages stoc:   
debug2: first_kex_follows 0   
debug2: reserved 0   
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256  
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512  
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com   MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30  
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY  
debug3: receive packet: type 31  
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa   SHA256:IXt+rhOgW2sc+qasp8jG0yreOq8qiYsOvluNjLvsSy8
debug3: put_host_port: [192.168.10.102]:6655  
debug3: put_host_port: [192.168.10.102]:6655  
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/mytsp00382/.ssh/known_hosts"  
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/mytsp00382/.ssh/known_hosts:3  
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [192.168.10.102]:6655  
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/mytsp00382/.ssh/known_hosts"  
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/mytsp00382/.ssh/known_hosts:3  
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [192.168.10.102]:6655  
debug1: Host '[192.168.10.102]:6655' is known and matches the RSA host key.  
debug1: Found key in /home/mytsp00382/.ssh/known_hosts:3  
debug3: send packet: type 21  
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1  
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent  
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS  
debug3: receive packet: type 21  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received  
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0  
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks  
debug2: key: /home/mytsp00382/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55a18f296050), agent  
debug2: key: /home/mytsp00382/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))  
debug2: key: /home/mytsp00382/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))  
debug2: key: /home/mytsp00382/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))  
debug3: send packet: type 5  
debug3: receive packet: type 7  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received  
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>  
debug3: receive packet: type 6  
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth  
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received  
debug3: send packet: type 50  
Connection closed by 192.168.10.102 port 6655
```

Comment: The verbose command is your only option. Since your real problem is the inability to connect to the server. You should probably provide us the verbose logs and server configuration file

Comment: Sure. I have provided the verbose log in the question. What could be reason for connection getting closed by the port?

Comment: that was closed on server side. If you can, look at the server logs there. A common reason is bad permissions on home directory or other files.